# Vuforia and Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I created a panel for showing some text according to image recognized using vuforia in unity. So when detected image targets are changed, the text should change according to that image target. I need c# code for that. Please help!

I already tried a code using elseif function, but it is not stable and it doesn't work as expected.

```cs
public class DataControllerCS002 : MonoBehaviour
{

    private DefaultTrackableEventHandler target;
    public Text winText;
    public GameObject EndPanel;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

        target = GetComponent<DefaultTrackableEventHandler>();
        winText.text = "SCAN QRCODE";


        EndPanel.SetActive(false);

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {


        if (target.liveobject == "qr1")
        {
            winText.text = "Walk Straight";

        }
        else if (target.liveobject == "qr1left2")
        {
            winText.text = "Walk Straight";
        }
        else if (target.liveobject == "left1")
        {
            winText.text = "Walk Straight";
        }
        else if (target.liveobject == "qrright1")
        {
            winText.text = "Walk Straight";
        }
        else if (target.liveobject == "qrright2")
        {
            winText.text = "Walk Straight";
        }
        else if (target.liveobject == "qrcenter")
        {
            winText.text = "Walk Left";
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What is your question? Statements like `it is not stable` and `it doesn't work as expected` don't help us to identify the issue. Please describe what exactly you expect to happen, and what happens instead. In general you should rather use a `switch - case` in this case or connect the conditions using `||` since you all the time want the same result

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do this in `update` function, but rather in event where `target.liveobject` value is changing. Do that there and you should be good to go.